# Maps v2: Prevent InfoWindow getting closed when moving map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm showing a marker with a info window, but everytime I am moving the map, the `InfoWindow` gets closed.
How can I prevent the InfoWindow from getting closed when moving the map or at least re-open it after the moving action is complete?

P.S.: I'm using the `Clusterkraf Library` if that makes any difference.

Comment: P.S. makes the difference. This is a known bug in Clusterkraf: https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf/issues/28. Try [Android Maps Extensions](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions) or [Android Maps Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils).

Answer (score 0):

Having had the same problem, I used a thread in MainActivity that tests (among others) the state of the current marker infowindow:

```
if (current_marker.isInfoWindowShown ()) 
             current_marker.showInfoWindow ();
```

Yes, it's strange, but it works...